# Android Studio - RecyclerView with API level 19 (API 19)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need to use RecyclerView with API 19 (API level 19).

I already have tried adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

and

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

in build.gradle but no success. I am new to Android development. I have checked 3-4 similar questions but no solution worked for me.
Please if someone can tell me all of the changes I need to make in build.gradle, XML and/or in manifest file?

Thank you!

Comment: "but no success" -- what do you mean, exactly? What are your symptoms? `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1` is the current release version, and it supports back to API Level 14.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was able to run project successfully after re-synching and re-building. Its working after using [[[implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0']]] in build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run successfully after re-synching and re-building. If anyone faces this issue in future then add

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

in build.gradle (Module) and then use

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

in XML. You will have to sync because of the change in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, apart from the things you mentioned, I also invalidate cache and restart. This helps me a lot sometimes.